# json_encode function not return Braces {} when array is empty in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this code

```
$status = array(
                "message"=>"error",
                "club_id"=>$_club_id,
                "status"=>"1",
                "membership_info"=>array(),
                );
```

`echo json_encode($status);`

This function return json:
`{"message":"error","club_id":275,"status":"1","membership_info":[]}`

But I need json like this:

`{"message":"error","club_id":275,"status":"1","membership_info":{}}`

Comment: that is how json represents an array. [] stands for an array in Json

Comment: What is the problem with the current format?

Comment: This is the correct json format. Arrays are enclosed in Braces - "[ ]".

Comment: @jogesh_pi The issue is that it generates inconsistent json (array when empty and object when not). Other parsers have issues with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725138/force-conversion-of-empty-json-array-to-dictionary-type

Comment: The first three comments here are not correct.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option of `json_encode`:

```
json_encode($status, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

> **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT (integer)**
>   Outputs an object rather than an array when a non-associative array is used. Especially useful when the recipient of the output is expecting an object and the array is empty. Available since PHP 5.3.0.

Or, if you want to preserve your "other" arrays inside your object, don't use the previous answer, just use this:

```
$status = array(
                "message"=>"error",
                "club_id"=>$_club_id,
                "status"=>"1",
                "membership_info"=> new stdClass()
                );
```

Comment: yeah the problem is that arrays like `["one"]` are then transformed into an object two, which is wrong.

Comment: The answer here answers the OP's question. You need to look at other answers to partially preserve arrays inside objects.

Comment: Bottom line: DO NOT use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT (unless you want your normal arrays mangled/curly-bracified). And in your JSON tree you must validate each object node for being empty and manually cast it to object or replace with `new StdClass()` ...

Answer (score 42):

```
$status = array(
                "message"=>"error",
                "club_id"=>$_club_id,
                "status"=>"1",
                "membership_info"=>(object) array(),
                );
```

By casting the array into an object, `json_encode` will always use braces instead of brackets for the value (even when empty).

This is useful when can't use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` and when you can't (or don't want) to use an actual object for the value.

Answer (score 8):

There's no difference in PHP between an array and an "object" (in the JSON sense of the word). If you want to force all arrays to be encoded as JSON objects, set the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag, available since PHP 5.3. See http://php.net/json_encode. Note that this will apply to *all* arrays.

Alternatively you could actually use *objects* in your PHP code instead of arrays:

```
$data = new stdClass;
$data->foo = 'bar';
...
```

Maybe it's simpler to handle the edge case of empty arrays client-side.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it's among the first hits on Google, so I thought I should share an alternative solution.

Rather than using standard PHP arrays, in PHP 7+ you can instead use `Map()` as part of the Data Structure extension. [Documentation.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-map.php)

A Map object has [practically identical performance](https://medium.com/@rtheunissen/efficient-data-structures-for-php-7-9dda7af674cd) as arrays and also implements ArrayAccess so it can be accessed as a regular array. Contrary to a standard array, however, it will always be associative and works as expected with `json_encode`. It also has some other minor benefits like object keys and better memory handling.

Some example usage:

```
use Ds\Map;

$status = new Map([
            "message"=>"error",
            "club_id"=>$_club_id,
            "status"=>"1",
            "membership_info"=>array(),
          ]);

$map = new Map(); 
print json_encode($map); // {}

$map = new Map();
$map["foo"] = "bar";
print json_encode($map); // {"foo":"bar"}
print $map["foo"]; // bar

$map = new Map();
$map[1] = "foo";
$map[2] = "bar";
$map[3] = "baz"; 
print json_encode($map); // {"1":"foo","2":"bar","3":"baz"}
```

Comment: it's a good solution but worth noticing that Data Structures is not a built-in PHP extension.

It needs to be installed before use. The [installation instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ds.installation.php) are available on php.net.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be considered *elegant*, a simple string replace can effectively address this.

```
str_replace("[]", "{}", json_encode($data));
```

This mitigates the issue of `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` converting a normal array into an object.

Comment: This won't work if there's `[]` inside a string: `str_replace('[]', '{}', json_encode(['key' => '[]']))` --> `{"key":"{}"}`