# Overwrite js plugin options via template

Tags: twig, shopware6

I have a problem to overwrite my JS plugin options from Twig.

My JS plugin options look like this:

```
static options = {
    configurator: {
        startTabIndex: 0,
        startModel: null,
        responsive: {
            xs: {
                startTabIndex: 1,
                startModel: 1
            },
            sm: {
                startTabIndex: 1,
                startModel: 1
            },
            md: {
                startTabIndex: 1,
                startModel: 1
            },
            lg: {},
            xl: {},
            xxl: {},
        },
    }
}
```

I am trying to overwrite these options from my template.

```
{% set configuratorOptions = {
    configurator: {
        startTabIndex: 1,
        startModel: 10,
        responsive: {
            xs: {},
            sm: {},
            md: {},
            lg: {},
            xl: {},
            xxl: {},
        },
    }
} %}

data-product-configurator-options="{{ configuratorOptions|json_encode }}
```

The values `startTabIndex` and `startModel` are working fine, but I want to empty the responsive settings like in the example above. After the option merge my options look like this and are not working properly. I think because the type switched from object to array.

```
{
    "configurator": {
        "startTabIndex": 1,
        "startModel": 10,
        "responsive": {
            "0": [],
            "576": [],
            "768": [],
            "992": [],
            "1200": [],
            "undefined": []
        }
    }
}
```

The getSettings function is not working with this. How do I prevent the type switch?

It works when I overwrite the responsive settings with values

Works

```
{% set configuratorOptions = {
    configurator: {
        startTabIndex: 1,
        startModel: 10,
        responsive: {
            sm: {
                startTabIndex: 123,
                startModel: 123,
            },
        },
    }
} %}
```

But I can't empty them.

Doesn't work

```
{% set configuratorOptions = {
    configurator: {
        startTabIndex: 1,
        startModel: 10,
        responsive: {
            sm: {},
        },
    }
} %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by passing the the following value, `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`, to the `flag` parameter of the `json_encode` filter

```
{% set configuratorOptions = {
    configurator: {
        startTabIndex: 1,
        startModel: 10,
        responsive: {
            xs: {},
            sm: {},
            md: {},
            lg: {},
            xl: {},
            xxl: {},
        },
    }
} %}


{{ configuratorOptions|json_encode(constant('JSON_FORCE_OBJECT'))|raw }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/nt5w6k)

---

*References*

- [json_encode function not return Braces {} when array is empty in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189390/json-encode-function-not-return-braces-when-array-is-empty-in-php)
- [Twig function constant](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/constant.html)
- [Twig filter json_encode](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/json_encode.html)

Comment: It keeps the braces now. They still don't emtpy the initial value, but thats a problem with the merge and for another topic. Thank you very much